# Caching strategy for UPS and USPS rate api results

Tags: design-patterns, caching, ups, usps

In trying to be a pragmatic programmer, I'm trying to work out a caching strategy for services and rates returned from the UPS and USPS apis.

My first thought would be to store following:

- postal code (normalized, no spaces, simply as a key)
- carrier
- weight
- service
- cost
- transit time
- country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha-2)

My primary goal is to set a short timeout for the API call, and fail over to cached data. For situations where "estimated" rates are acceptable (ex: shipping calculator on a shopping cart), I plain to use the cached data first.

**EDIT** I fully intend to prime this cache on a regular basis from existing user data.

Comment: Hi Eric, I'm sure I could help you with this, but I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. Are you asking how to use a cache to store this data?

Comment: I was wondering if anybody had any suggestions on what to store. More of a question about design-pattern rather than actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you answered your own question. When looking at weight I'd cache the billable weight based on DIM size if you have it as that's the largest variance.